Using cairo on Windows x64
I have to get the dominant color of an svg file. So my plan is to convert the SVG to a PNG and for this I wanted to use cairo. After the default package installation in PyCharm I get an
OSError: OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'

So I have searched for a solution and found this GTK3 x64 with cffi in it. After the installation and following the instructions of weasyprint I still get the same error. Maybe there is something wrong with the import?
from cffi import cairo

I still tried it with installing pycairo, but nothing changed :/
Another try was to install it through pipwin like in this post, but it throws an KeyError
